# SerialPort.ReadLine Property Usage

Tags: c#, serial-port, readline

I've a little question to ask.

I need to read data from serial port. The data come line by line(I mean data + enter)
Do I have to set the serialPort property new line as below?

```
SerialPort sp = new SerialPort();
sp.NewLine = "\r";
sp.ReadLine();
```

What is the value for newline property?
My best regards...

Answer (score 2):

It depends on the protocol you are using. This mean that this is the subject of agreement for sending and receiving parts.

If the other side uses .NET on windows most probably the new line wold be *Environment.NewLine* and you could skip setting it because it is default value on windows.

In general, default new line sequences are:
for windows '\r\n'
for mac '\r'
for linux '\n'
custom controller - whatever the developer of the controller put there

Thus if you write a software to receive something from linux, you might await '\n' as a NewLine value, etc.

If you have data exchange with some controller (exchange with some device) the NewLine string could be WHATEVER the device software developer set it.

If you develop this protocol and are in doubt to set NewLine or not, I could suggest you to set if you assume that your application may run in multiplatform environment (I.E. sender on windows, receiver on linux).

Comment: Than you should present data coming from the other side as sequence of bytes and see what the line ending sequence coming from there.

Comment: I remember one case when the the device developer set NewLine as '\0' to be easy to read in C.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried

```
 sp.NewLine = Environment.NewLine;
```