# Data received from serial port has incorrect new line characters

Tags: c#, serial-port

I have written an application that sends data to COM port and receives returned data.

Sending works great, but receiving doesn't. New line characters in multiline and readonly textbox are incorrect.

Screenshot:

[image]

My code for receiving is:

```
void serialPort_DataReceived(object s, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
    byte[] data = new byte[_serialPort.BytesToRead];
    _serialPort.Read(data, 0, data.Length);

    string str = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(data);

    textBox3.Text = textBox3.Text + str;

    textBox3.SelectionStart = textBox3.TextLength;
    textBox3.ScrollToCaret();
}
```

And before opening the port I am setting New Line property to \r\n:

```
_serialPort.NewLine = "\r\n";
```

How to fix this?

Answer (score 4):

From [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.ports.serialport.newline%28VS.80%29.aspx):

> Gets or sets the value used to interpret the end of a call to the
> ReadLine and WriteLine methods.

The key there is that it's uses ***to interpret*** the end of a call, not to ***set*** it.

The NewLine property handles how the SerialPort object tries to interpret the incoming data.  It doesn't manipulate the incoming data.

In other words, by seting the NewLine property to "\r\n" you're telling it to ***look for*** "\r\n" and use that as a NewLine character.

The data coming into the serial port is what it is.  You can't change how someone else sends the data. (Unless you wrote that app as well.)  You can only tell the SerialPort how to try to read the data properly.

What you need to do is figure out what the program is sending you and set the .NewLine prperty to *that*.  Most likely it's just sending either just "\n" or just "\r", so if you set the NewLIne property to match, your program will start properly recognizing the newline characters being sent to it.

There is a bit more info that may help at [SerialPort.ReadLine Property Usage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9079595/serialport-readline-property-usage)

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
_serialPort.NewLine = Environment.NewLine;
```

Comment: Possible problem with this approach is that since the data is coming in over a COM port, it is likely coming from another computer which may or may not be using the same environment (or even the same OS for that matter).

Answer (score 2):

The solution is:

```
textBox3.Text = textBox3.Text + str.Replace("\r", "\r\n");
```